# How to get the app's user when the app is loaded from graph api?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am having a serious problem with my app. While installing the app, my app will ask the user in which page he wants to install it. Suppose the user select a page and says install. The app will be installed.

Now When a visitor visits that page, the app will also load. What I want to do is I want to get the user id of the person who actually installed the app, using a javascript code.

Can anyone help me fix this? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: My question is similar to this

http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=89823

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store that off someplace on your installation, either in the site itself, or back on your server and then call back to it to get the user/page combo, I don't know of any other way to do it.

Comment: Ok, suppose that I saved the user's details somewhere say my server, there will be many users who are going to add my app. Suppose a visitor visited a user who has installed my app, then how can I get the app installer's name or data?

Comment: When they install the app, does it still run on your server, or is it running on their server from that point on?

Comment: My thought on that is that when the app is installed on the users page, that you would have a specific tag/ID on the page that identifies that instance, and then sends that information back to your server.  Then when the app runs, it uses that tag/ID to register.  That tag/ID will map to the UserID of the person that installed it, and all calls to FB would be from that ID.  About all I can think of right now.

Comment: Actually when the app is loaded fb sends a signed_request request parameter to the app. Through that we can get the user's page. This link has the information http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/  Thanks for your efforts @Jeff